# Timeout Error while using selenium firefox webdriver in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, firefox

I am trying to use selenium firefox webdriver to navigate to a page and initiate a click event. This event should paste a csv data onto the clipboard. Upon executing this code the firefox window pops up without any url in the address bar and then I get the following error message:

Error: TimeoutError
Firefox failed to open the listening port 127.0.0.1:12825 with 15s

Here is my code

```
Set objFireFox = CreateObject("Selenium.FirefoxDriver")
objFireFox.Get "https://chartink.com/screener/practical-swing-trading-stock-scanner", 20000, False
objFireFox.FindElementsByClass("btn btn-default buttons-copy buttons-html5 btn-primary").Click
```

Initially I was using the following statement

```
objFireFox.Get "https://chartink.com/screener/practical-swing-trading-stock-scanner"
```

then I modified it to

```
objFireFox.Get "https://chartink.com/screener/practical-swing-trading-stock-scanner", 20000, False
```

but still the error message was same in both cases. I have downloaded the latest version of mozilla/geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.30.0

Thanks

Comment: Does the latest version correspond with the version of FF on your computer?

Comment: I have no idea about compatibility :) I just downloaded the SeleniumBasic from github. The project was marked as latest. As for my Firefox it is always up to date. So SeleniumBasic version is 2.0.9.0 and My Firefox version is 93.0 (64bit)

Comment: You have to ensure that the version of the firefox webdriver (a component of SeleniumBasic) matches the version of FF you have on your computer.  I don't use FF but with chrome or edge, sometimes the latest web driver can be ahead of the version I have on my computer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have noticed in the seleniumbasic installation directory that, there is a .exe file for all the corresponding webdrivers (e.g. chromedriver.exe, edgedriver.exe etc), but there is a firefox.xpi for firefox webdriver. If I download latest firefoxdriver/geckodriver, which is the file named geckodriver.exe, then shouls I copy it to the seleniumbasic installation directory? Also all the webdrivers get registered in the registry during intallation, so i am not sure if just copying the geckodriver.exe to the folder will be effective.

Comment: That's what I do with the chrome and edge drivers.  But I'm not sure of the procedure for the ff drivers. Perhaps try running the .exe and see if it generates an xpi file? But you still have to be sure to match the driver versions, and latest may not necessarily match.

Comment: I feel that I should switch from VBA to Python, for my current project. I see that support for Python is way much more than VBA. Thanks @Ron Rosenfeld for the help. I guess, I will soon be posting question related to Selenium in Python :)